# As a front end developer ,how can i easily hide my api

Tags: javascript, mern, api-key

I have a front end project. html,css and js , all I want is to hide my api keys in the back end ...nothing less nothing more ...chatgbt is giving me more than I can handle with all these cors (can't get past it,
probably already have I don't even know), proxy stuff and this bot keeps forget our previous messages and treat my questions as if they are just random leading to more errors. For now i will just do something along the lines of ...connecting vscode => github ,doing the environment variables e.t.c saw Kyle from webdev simplified do it once ...i will try that while waiting for a response .

I tried hiding my API keys, or more accurately .I tried to make chatgbt do it. Then failed dismal style

Comment: `chatgbt` (sic) can't write code for you. You've shown no code. What is your problem?

Comment: put it in environment variables